# OnSuccess fuction in Ajax.BeginForm not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following form that opens in a Bootstrap modal at my page:

```
<div id="myModalLogin" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Sign in</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "target",
                    OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess"
                }))
                {
                    <div class="sign_up_container">
                        Email:<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Login.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "sign_up_container_input_style" } })<br/>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Login.Email, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="sign_up_container">
                        Password:<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Login.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "sign_up_container_input_style" } })
                        <br/><a href="#">Forgott password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sign_up_container">
                        <br />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn_style_3 btn">Login</button>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just below I have my JavaScript:

```
<script>

    function ajaxSuccess(result) {
        console.log("hello");
       console.log(result)
    }
</script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Login(homeIndexViewModel model)
{
    return Json("hej");
}
```

The problem I have Is that the ajaxSuccess is never fired. When I inspect the console, I can see that a POST is made and the response contains the value "hej" from the controller. But my JavaScript function is not fired.

I have included the following JavaScript files:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

I have also enabled:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

A ajax-post is made, but my OnSuccess-function is never fired.

Comment: everything seems fine except one might be `UpdateTargetId` is correct ?

Comment: der is one thing i want you to try is just put a simple alert there `            OnSuccess = "alert()",` and see is it work ?